# Angular Leaflet Directive yielding many GET file://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/17/38591/49266.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, directive

I'm trying to experiment with the Leaflet Angular directive.  I've followed some seemingly simple steps but no map is displayed and I'm getting a bunch of errors in my console similar to:

GET file://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/17/38591/49266.png net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Here's my controller:

```
app.controller('MainController', [ '$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.mapCenter = { lat: 40.741934, lng: -74.004897, zoom: 17 }
}]);
```

And here's the markup:

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
    <div class="container-fluid" id="map-canvas">
        <leaflet center="mapCenter"></leaflet>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you have not fixed your issue already, that is because you open your web page from file system, rather than through a (potentially local) host / server, and because the [Angular Leaflet Directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) default Tile Layer URL template [does not specify the protocol](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/src/services/leafletMapDefaults.js#L26).

Therefore, your browser re-uses the same protocol used to open your page, i.e. `file://`. But of course you do not have the OSM tiles on your file system, so the browser cannot retrieve any tile.

You can easily fix the issue by opening your page through a server, or by specifying the URL template of your Tile Layer, including `http://` or `https://` protocol. In order to do so, you have to extend your `$scope` with a `tiles` property, which is an object with at least `url` property.

Probably something like:

```js
angular.extend($scope, {
    tiles: {
        url: "http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
        options: {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }
    }
});
```

See for example: http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-leaflet-directive/#!/examples/tiles

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!  Worked perfectly with a server.

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. Thank you for the feedback! Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to **accept** the answer that helped you. Once you have enough "reputation", you will also have the ability to "upvote".

Comment: All set (I believe).  I though because of my limited reputation I also couldn't accept an answer.